# Would a polytope with the Schläfli symbol {5,3,2} have more five-fold symmetry for its level of complexity than any other polytope?

Tags: geometry

Being someone who idly ponders the very nature of Mathematics, Science, and the Universe at all scales, despite not having a college degree, nor the monetary costs to attain one, I've gained a sort of rudimentary, and unrefined sort of "instinct" of inherent relationships and connections between things.

As such, this is purely a very mildly-educated hunch of mine.

My thought process was:

A pentagon {5} is practically flooded with the golden ratio and 5-fold symmetry, as is a Regular Dodecahedron {5,3}. Both of them have extreme difficulty appearing in nature because of this.

I knew that.

Today though, I realized that the numbers in the Schläfli symbols were starting to follow the fibonacci sequence.

I deeply felt that this couldn't be a simple coincidence, since, as I've realized, if two things coincide strongly enough in a Mathematical or Scientific context, it tends to not actually be a coincidence at all.

I realized, that perhaps a polytope with a Schläfli symbol of {5,3,2} would likely absolutely and debilitatingly ***reek*** of five-fold symmetry and the golden ratio.

It also could effectively be the absolute most forbidden shape in all of theoretical nature.

So what I'm asking is: am I correct in this rudimentary, amateurish hunch?

Comment: $\{5,3,2\}=\{5,3\}$ (degenerately). Also note the Strong Law of Small Numbers.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel So iff I'm understanding this correctly, in my very ham-fisted method of re-explaining what you said, {5} is to {5,3}, as {5,3} is to {5,3,2} (in terms of the latter object being primarily composed of the former object, just within one extra spatial dimension). That makes perfect sense to me. I'll certainly have to learn more about the Strong Law of Small Numbers, since my knowledge of mathematics utterly, utterly pales in comparison to virtually all other people acting within this wonderful corner of the internet. Thank you for tolerating my highly uneducated perspective of math.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Ah, so iff my "research" was sufficient, that law is a mathematical in-joke, and quite possibly one about people like me, and people similar to me, that archetypically went completely over my head, and very archetypically made me look like even more of a fool than I already did. All I have to say is simply: "Touché". I'm still not going to let anything stop me from keeping on learning about ever-more things. Edit: What I said isn't true at all, and I just

Comment: Edit 2: I mis-clicked send, and a 5-minute timer that I didn't know existed expired. What I was trying to say, was that that huge misunderstanding of mine perfectly illustrates just how much anxiety and fear I have over looking like a fool in front of like-minded, smart people.